# Set a variable value within a jar using a gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a client and server architecture.

The client is a runnable `.jar` file built using the following Gradle task:

```
jar {
    archiveName = "app.jar"
    from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    include '**/*.class'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.bobbyrne01.app.Main'
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

I'm making a change to how this client will authenticate.

The problem is, I'd like to specify which method of authentication the client should use during the build.

So that when the user downloads the `.jar`, they will just run it and whichever method of authentication I activated during the build will be active in the `.jar`.

What would be the best way to set this `authenticationType` variable/flag?

For the server, there is an interface for authentication and a number of classes which implement different authentication methods. While building the server, I specify a gradle property which gets set as an environment variable on the docker image.
So at runtime, the server uses reflection to determine which authentication class to instantiate.

But I'm unsure how I can set a similar value within the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a properties file containing a value allowing to decide, at runtime, which authentication mechanism you want to use.

Define it as

```
authentication=${authentication} or
```

or

```
authentication=@@authentication@@
```

in the source properties file. And use expand or filter in the standard `processResources` gradle task (of type `Copy`) in order to replace the placeholder by the actual value you want to use.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:expand(java.util.Map) and https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:filter(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class).